# How to increase/decrease current margin at a number by jquery?

Tags: jquery

Given an element with unknown margin-left, how to increase its margin-left at a number say 100px?

For example:

assuming the original margin-left is 100px

the expected result is 100px + 100px thus 200px finally.

Comment: Fetch the current value, add 100, write it back? Is your question about how to fetch the current value?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
$('#element-id').css('margin-left', function (index, curValue) {
    return parseInt(curValue, 10) + 100 + 'px';
});
```

curValue will include 'px' at the end, so you'll end up with `NaN` or `100px100px` as your result without using `parseInt` first.

Comment: Just to be on the safe side, you can make sure you currently have some margins before adding.
    `var actualMargin = parseInt(curValue);
    if (isNaN(actualMargin)) {
        actualMargin = 0;
    }`

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 20):

A quick/terse way to do this:

```
$('#IDHere').animate({marginLeft: '+=100px'}, 0);
```

[Here's a quick example of this](http://jsfiddle.net/Cy6y9/).  The `0` makes this happen in a single frame, if you actually want to animate it, change the `0` to the number of milliseconds you want, [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Cy6y9/1/).

Comment: @Relax - The `0` isn't an animation, it's a 1 frame CSS update, isn't it quicker to click the link and see this working than immediately dismissing it?  That's a bad approach, and you'll miss out learning a lot of new things that way, just something to think about.

Comment: I prefer with value change, but i think this way will also work and your idea is creative, :)

Answer (score 5):

You can simply achieve this using just .css (see example below)

```
$('#element-id').css('margin-left', '+=100px');
```

Comment: nice one,  i didn't know you could do that!

Answer (score 1):

```
$("p").css({marginLeft: function(index, value) {
    return parseFloat(value) + 100;
}});
```