# Adding current margin value to another value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My question is similar to: [How to increase/decrease current margin at a number by jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781887/how-to-increase-decrease-current-margin-at-a-number-by-jquery) however I cannot adapt the solution to match my code. I keep getting errors.

My CSS defines $logo variable with a margin-top of -82px. In my JS below, the margin-top value is being adjusted on scroll but it assumes the start value for margin-top is 0. How do I say its -82px?

Here's a jsfiddle of the glitch: http://jsfiddle.net/5DAa9/ Carefully scroll down and you will notice the box jump.

```
var $logo = $('.logo.abbr');
var windowScroll;
var $curValue = $( '.logo.abbr' ).css( "margin-top" );

    // Functional parallaxing calculations
    function slidingTitle() {

        //Get scroll position of window
        windowScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

        //Slow scroll of .logo and fade it out
        $logo.css({
            'margin-top' : ($curValue-(windowScroll/3)+"px") // Assuming this is the line I need to change??
        });

    }
```

Comment: I don't get the box jump, what browser are you using?

Comment: @htmltroll Latest Chrome

Comment: I see the box jump... Is your goal just to get the box to not move at all or move with the scroll?

Comment: Lol where did you get your fiddle's page content? It's pretty vulgar... I like it. :)

Comment: @Kierchon I want the box to begin moving from the spot it loads in, i don't want it to jump down 82px as soon as you begin to scroll. I want it to move up from its original place without the jump down.

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte lol. Courtesy of http://slipsum.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres a quick fix...

```
windowScroll = $(this).scrollTop()+250;
```

Why this is happening I have no idea. Im gonna keep poking around to see if I can figure it out but this is working for me here

http://jsfiddle.net/5DAa9/1/

**Edit:**

I have found the problem!!

`windowScroll = $(this).scrollTop();` This line will return 0 if the page is at the top. You have set your margin to be -82px before the scroll so that just gets erased on the first scroll and set back to 0 or whatever the scroll is divided by 3. So you want to do that calculation and then subtract the 82 pixels again to keep it in the "same place" or prevent the jump.

```
$logo.css({
'margin-top' : -(windowScroll/3)-82+"px"
});
```

Its kind of an ugly fix but thats whats going on. I assume that 250 of whatever scaling scrollTop returns is equivalent to 82px. Heres an updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5DAa9/3/