# Problems creating Chrome extension that widens margins with keystroke

Tags: jquery, json, google-chrome-extension

I'm sure some might be tempted to tell me just to use Stylebot to alter the CSS of pages instead of making my own extension, but Stylebot is overkill and therefore too clunky for what I want to do. I just want to widen the left margin widen by 100px every time I hit Ctrl+M.

I think I have two key issues:

1. It's not completely clear (to me) from the documentation how to *change* a
   margin (as opposed to setting one, although my attempts to do that
   have failed as well). It's not clear how something like the jquery
   in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781887/how-to-increase-decrease-current-margin-at-a-number-by-jquery) could be fit into the template provided by [this
   example](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/browserAction/make_page_red/background.js) on the documentation (and yes, I've tried that with jquery
   included as a background script).
2. I sense that maybe I'm supposed to use `tab` somehow as in
   `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab)` but can't tell how for sure from the documentation.

Here's one version (in background.js) of many of what I've tried, using code from the SO answer linked above:

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {
  if (command == "Ctrl+M") { 
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({code: "$('body').css('margin-left', function(index, curValue) {return parseInt(curValue, 10) + 100 + 'px'}"
  });
 }
});
```

And here's the manifest in case that's where the problem lies:

```
{
  "name": "MarginAdjust",
  "description": "Widen margins of websites with Ctrl+M, narrow them with Ctrl+B.",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "commands": {
    "widen_margin": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+M",
        "mac": "Command+M"
      },
      "description": "Widens margin."
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for any guidance. I've even looked at the Stylebot source code to try to see how they did it but was unable to figure it out.

EDIT: It may be because I need a content_script to modify a page, but apparently [chrome.commands doesn't work with content_scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24226994/chrome-extension-error-with-oncommand)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content script will be executed in a special isolate world. It can access the DOM nodes in the injected web page and completely separate the JavaScript on the page from the javascript in extension. So if you want to inject a code which will manipulate DOM elements by using jQuery library, you need to inject jQuery lib to web page first.

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "jquery.min.js"});
chrome.tabs.executeScript({code: "$('body').css('margin-left', function(index, curValue) {return parseInt(curValue, 10) + 100 + 'px'});"});
```

Content script injection can be triggered by chrome.command callback. The value of the first parameter of onCommand callback will be the command name which you declare in manifest.json. The key combination you defined in "suggested_key" will take effect only if the key is not already assign to another command. "Ctrl + M" seems not work and "Ctrl+Shift+K" worked for me.

```
"commands": {
  "widen_margin": {
    "suggested_key": {
      "default": "Ctrl+Shift+K"
    },
  "description": "Widens margin."
  }
}
```

One more thing to keep in mind when developing/testing hot keys related extension is that you need to re-install the extension in order to examine the updated commands setting. The command setting of extension will be adopted when it is the first time installing.

I wrote a simple example, you could refer to it

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name":"MarginAdjust",
    "description": "Widen margins of websites with Ctrl+M, narrow them with Ctrl+B.",
    "version": "1",
    "manifest_version":2,
    "permissions": [
      "activeTab"
    ],
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"],
      "persistent": false
    },
    "commands": {
      "widen_margin": {
        "suggested_key": {
          "default": "Ctrl+Shift+K"
        },
        "description": "Widens margin."
      }
    }
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {
  alert(command);
  if (command == "widen_margin") { 
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "jquery.min.js"});
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({code: "$('body').css('margin-left', function(index, curValue) {return parseInt(curValue, 10) + 100 + 'px'});"});
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked!! (I initially got an error -- I have no idea why -- but then it worked (and not because I reloaded the file, because I was already doing that).)  Apart from the jQuery injection, it may have also been because my `if` statement used `Ctrl+Shift+K` instead of `widen_margin`. I'm no longer sure where I saw the former used. 

One quick question: what's the purpose of `null` in your first `executeScript`? Since I'm using the default of that parameter anyway (active tab) and the script works without it, I'm just curious as to why you included it.

Comment: The first parameter stands for tabID, it's optional. You could ignore it or pass null to it if you only want to execute content script on the active tab.

Comment: Gotcha. Btw, the injection of jquery.min creates a lag time for me of about 2 seconds, so I've decided to try injecting CSS.