# Increment style.marginLeft with each click?

Tags: javascript

I'm building a basic slider with JavaScript. Each time button is clicked, div slide should increment its `margin-left "-100px"`.

I have this code:

```
document.getElementById('core-next').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('slides').style.marginLeft = "-100px";
}
```

And it works in a way that when I click `#core-next` margin gets set to -100px.
But what I want to achieve is that every time I click a button, margin increases by `-100px`.

So it looks like: `-100px, -200px, -300px...`

Is this possible in pure JavaScript? jQuery has `"+="`! Can I do this in Javascript wihout adding additional variable?

I tried this:

```
document.getElementById('core-next').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('slides').style.marginLeft -= 200 + 'px';
}
```

But its not working...

Is there a way to achieve this in JavaScript, without creating additional variable that will hold margin value?

Thanks!

Comment: refer [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781887/how-to-increase-decrease-current-margin-at-a-number-by-jquery) you might get solution!

Answer (score 0):

That property is a string so first you need to read it, parse it to a int and then change the value and reset it. Something like this:

```
document.getElementById('core-next').onclick = function() {
    var slides = document.getElementById('slides');
    // Read it and parse to an int
    var marginLeft =  parseInt(slides.style.marginLeft, 10);
    // Subtract value, add pixel back in and reset property
    slides.style.marginLeft = (marginLeft - 100) + 'px';
}
```

If you really need it in one line you could do this:

```
document.getElementById('slides').style.marginLeft = (parseInt(document.getElementById('slides').style.marginLeft, 10) - 100) + 'px';
```

But this solution while it doesn't have a variable holding the value and is one line isn't great since it calls getElementById twice for same value.

Answer (score 0):

you can use parseInt function to remove px from marginLeft string. First parameter is the input string and the second one is the radix.

```
var slides = document.getElementById('slides');
document.getElementById('core-next').onclick = function() {
    slides.style.marginLeft = (parseInt(slides.style.marginLeft, 10) - 100) + 'px';
}
```